# Using only one instance of a class between more projects in WPF PRISM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

I'm beginner in WPF.
I've encountered something, that I can't solve.
I'm working on an application that consist of 8 projects. (8 module PRISM)
I'm using MVVM pattern too. I use some of my viewmodels in other projects/modules.
I'd like it if these viewmodels were only one instance in my application. These contain ObservableCollections and these ObservableCollections contains records of a dataset.
I tried to use dependency injection to, but I couldn't solve the problem.
I don't know how register a class or I don't know exactly how should I solve the problem.

Can everybody help me?

## EDIT1

Yesterday I did some changes. For Example in the `DataManipulationModule` `Initialize` function.

DataManipulationModule:

```
namespace PriceCalculator.Modules.DataManipulation
{
    [Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.DataManipulationModule)]
    [ModuleDependency(ModuleNames.MainMenuModule)]
    public class DataManipulationModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;

        public DataManipulationModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.container = container;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, () => this.container.Resolve<Views.DataManipulationView>());
        }
    }
}
```

My DataManipulationViewModelController constructor:

```
public DataManipulationViewModelController(IRegionManager regionManager, ButorlapViewModel blmodel)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
            MainMenuViewUri = new Uri(ViewUriNames.MainMenuView, UriKind.Relative);

            backToMainMenuCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.BackToMainMenu, this.CanBackToMainMenu);

            canBackToMainMenu = new bool[10] { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };


            this.butorlapViewModel = blmodel;
            tomorfaViewModel = new TomorfaViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            dekoranyagViewModel = new DekoranyagViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            megmunkalasViewModel = new MegmunkalasViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            specMegmunkalasViewModel = new SpecMegmunkalasViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            elzarasViewModel = new ElzarasViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            kiegeszitoViewModel = new KiegeszitoViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            munkadijViewModel = new MunkadijViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            vevoViewModel = new VevoViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);
            szorzoViewModel = new SzorzoViewModel(backToMainMenuCommand);


            InitViewModelController();
        }
```

## EDIT2

After that I changed my `Bootstrapper` too. I've added a function.

Bootstrapper ConfigureContainer funtcion:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
                {
                    base.ConfigureContainer();
                    this.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(PriceCalculator.Common.ViewModels.ButorlapViewModel), new PriceCalculator.Common.ViewModels.ButorlapViewModel());
                }
```

This solved my problem partly. So there is already on instance of `ButorlapViewModel`, but if I change the ObservablCollection in this class, something will be bad again, because it seems like it would be more instance again. It diplays not the same values on one screen like on another screen after repopulate my `ObservableCollection`.

Can anyone help me please?

## EDIT3

I've solved the problem. The injection was good. The problem was another place.

So the right injection looks like as following. This is my bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            base.ConfigureContainer();

            this.Container.RegisterType<BaseViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

            this.Container.RegisterType<DataManipulationViewModelController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            this.Container.RegisterType<NewPriceCalculationViewModelController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
```

And this is one of my constructors in which I injected:

```
public DataManipulationViewModelController(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer unityContainer)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
            MainMenuViewUri = new Uri(ViewUriNames.MainMenuView, UriKind.Relative);

            backToMainMenuCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.BackToMainMenu, this.CanBackToMainMenu);

            canBackToMainMenu = new bool[10] { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

            this.baseViewModel = unityContainer.Resolve<BaseViewModel>();
        }
```

Thank you for everybody.

Comment: What specific problems did you have with trying to use DI ? Please illustrate with relevant code samples.

Comment: When your DataManipulationViewModelController gets created, isn't a ButorlapViewModel instance being passed in by prism through your ctor ?

Comment: What container are you using?